# Is a moved-from shared_ptr guaranteed to be emptied?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, shared-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
struct Bar
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> MemberFunction()
    {
        return std::move(m_memberVariable);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<int> m_memberVariable;
};
```

Is it guaranteed that the `std::move` from a `shared_ptr<T>` will actually remove the reference in the member variable? Or should I copy, clear and return copy to guarantee this*

Clearly in the case of `unique_ptr<T>` it does the right thing (it cannot possibly not do) but does the standard *guarantee* that a `std::move`d from `shared_ptr` releases its reference? [when it is a *member variable*, *static* or *global*, locals don't matter as they go out of scope]

*possibly "swap and return" is better than "copy, clear and return".

Comment: Do you want in practice, or do you want chapter-and-verse from the standard?  In practice, even if the standard missed insisting on this, any compiler which did it would be considered evil.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do indeed have that guarantee. From 20.7.2.2.1/21-22:

> `shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& r) noexcept;`
>
> `template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&& r) noexcept;`
>
> Effects: Move-constructs a `shared_ptr` instance from `r`.
>
> Postconditions: `*this` shall contain the old value of `r`. **`r` shall be empty. `r.get() == 0`**.